# Finding the Difference Quotient of a function Using Python

Tags: python, return, calculus

I am reading Data Science From Scratch by Joel Grus, and am stuck on understanding how a simple difference quotient function works using python.
Here is the code:

`f` is a function of a one variable function, dependent on `x`, as `h` approaches 0.

```
def difference_quotient(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h
```

I understand that this is just the equation for finding the limit, and in this case the derivative, but I don't see how the script works.  What arguments would you put into the function that would allow for a return statement of `f(something)` and not `f*(something)`.  So far I keep getting errors such as 'float'/'dict' object is not callable.

Comment: Apparently `f` is supposed to be a function that you're passing in to `difference_quotient` for it to call. So `f(x+h)` and f(x)` are calling the function you passed in with different arguments.

Comment: FWIW, Joel Grus is a SO member http://stackoverflow.com/users/1076346/joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Someone" has answered your question but you (and future readers) may find this supplementary information useful.

To get an accurate approximation of the derivative you need to make `h` fairly small. However, if you make it too small then you actually lose accuracy due to the limited precision of Python floats. You can get more precision by using the `decimal` module. However, that module only supports simple arithmetic operators and the square root function. If you need fancier functions like trigonometric or exponential functions, then you can use a 3rd-party package arbitrary-precision mathemtaics package such as the excellent [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org), although if you do use `mpmath` then you'd probably use its [numerical derivative functions](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/differentiation.html).

FWIW, you can make the derivative approximation more accurate (for a given `h`) by making `x` the middle of the interval. Here's a short demo:

```
def dfa(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h

def dfb(f, x, h):
    hh = 0.5 * h 
    return (f(x + hh) - f(x - hh)) / h

# The function
def func(x): return x**3 + x*x + x + 1

# Its exact derivative
def dfunc(x): return 3*x*x + 2*x + 1

h = 0.001
for i in range(10):
    x = 1 + 0.1 * i
    print(x, dfunc(x), dfb(func, x, h), dfa(func, x, h))
```

**output**

```
1.0 6.0 6.00000024999936 6.004000999999093
1.1 6.830000000000001 6.830000249999024 6.8343009999995985
1.2 7.719999999999999 7.72000024999997 7.724600999999609
1.3 8.67 8.670000249998644 8.674900999999124
1.4 9.68 9.680000249999487 9.685200999998145
1.5 10.75 10.750000249998948 10.755500999998446
1.6 11.880000000000003 11.880000249998801 11.885800999996476
1.7000000000000002 13.070000000000002 13.07000024999816 13.07610099999934
1.8 14.32 14.320000249997022 14.326400999998157
1.9 15.629999999999999 15.630000249997167 15.636700999996478
```

Here are the results for the exponential function.

```
from math import exp

def dfa(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h

def dfb(f, x, h):
    hh = 0.5 * h 
    return (f(x + hh) - f(x - hh)) / h

func = dfunc = exp

h = 0.001
for i in range(10):
    x = 1 + 0.1 * i
    print(x, dfunc(x), dfb(func, x, h), dfa(func, x, h))
```

**output**

```
1.0 2.718281828459045 2.718281941720413 2.7196414225332255
1.1 3.0041660239464334 3.0041661491195804 3.005668607777512
1.2 3.3201169227365472 3.320117061074157 3.3217775346887635
1.3 3.6692966676192444 3.669296820505874 3.6711319276547805
1.4 4.0551999668446745 4.0552001358102885 4.057228242863253
1.5 4.4816890703380645 4.481689257074706 4.483930662008362
1.6 4.953032424395115 4.953032630771403 4.955509766318755
1.7000000000000002 5.473947391727201 5.473947619807795 5.476685277975513
1.8 6.0496474644129465 6.049647716480422 6.0526732966712515
1.9 6.6858944422792685 6.685894720857455 6.689238504094419
```

Note that `dfb` is not foolproof: if you're trying to find the derivative for an `x` value that's near a pole or discontinuity, then shifting the interval to include the pole or discontinuity can give erroneous results. Of course, you can get the same problem with `dfa`, eg if `f(x) = 1/x` and `x` is a negative number but `x+h` is positive.

Answer (score 4):

f is the function you are trying to find the derivative/difference quotient of at x.

Try this code: (python 3)

```
def difference_quotient(f, x, h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x)) / h

def func(x):
    # this is f of x, the function you are taking the derivative of
    return x * x

print(difference_quotient(func, 2, 0.001))
```

Comment: @Mwspencer No problem, If it did the trick then make sure to close the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png